# Specify that an interface can only be implemented by reference types C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface, reference-type

If I declare an interface in C#, is there any way I can explicitly declare that any type implementing that interface is a reference type?

The reason I want to do this is so that wherever I use the interface as a type parameter, I don't have to specify that the implementing type also has to be a reference type.

Example of what I want to accomplish:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    void A();
    int B { get; }
}

public class UsingType<T> where T : IInterface
{
    public void DoSomething(T input)
    {
         SomeClass.AnotherRoutine(input);
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public static void AnotherRoutine<T>(T input)
        where T : class
    {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```

As the argument to `SomeClass.AnotherRoutine()` is required to be a reference type, I will here get a compiler error where I call the method, suggesting that I force `T` to be a reference type (`where T : IInterface, class` in the declaration of `UsingType`). Is there any way I can enforce this already at the interface level?

```
public interface IInterface : class
```

doesn't work (obviously) but maybe there's another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: It seems like the type would be an implementation detail, which is what the interface attempts to abstract away in the first place.  I'm curious; why do you want to only allow reference type implementations?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this, but is it really that much more work to add an additional `where` clause on your `UsingType<>` class(es)?

Comment: @Ed: In my specific case, I have an interface `IEntity` that I let all my business entities implement. Entity Framework demands that all entity types are reference types, so for all interactions with EF this is required. Since I know that I don't want any entity types that aren't reference types, I'd like to specify that already on the interface.

Comment: @Cameron: No, it's really not *that* much of a work-saver, but since I ran into a case where I wanted to do it, I figured I'd ask. If nothing else, I'll learn more about the C# language =)

Comment: What happens when this interface is implemented by a struct type?  Is an exception thrown when it is used by EF?  If so, it seems like that would be safe enough.

Comment: @Ed: Since EF requires the type to be a reference type, the code won't compile without me adding the extra type constraint; thus, no struct will ever get that far.

Comment: Use an abstract base class instead of an interface.

Comment: @bentayloruk: It's a good idea and I'll consider it, but if I do that I will cripple my abilities to inherit other classes. What if I want `Foo` to inherit `Bar` and implement `IInterface`, but I don't want/need `Bar` to? Mabye `Bar` is a class I don't have control over, so I can't go all the way down the chain and make the root object inherit `AbstractFoo`...

Comment: @tomas-lycken As C# does not support multiple inheritance, using an abstract base class will prevent you from inheriting from other types. And yes, it will be a problem if you are using exiting types, or 3rd party types that don't inherit from the abstract base class.  I would suggest you bite the bullet and use the class constraint where you use T.  This is the right thing to do. ReSharper will add this for you if it is the typing you object to :)  If you do use the abstract base class, you can utilise other types to implement interfaces via composition.

Answer (score 4):

If you are passing something around under an interface, then even if you have a value type implementing that interface it will become boxed if cast to the interface and behave like a reference type (because it is boxed inside a reference type).

```
interface IFoo {
    int Value { get; set; }
}

struct Foo : IFoo {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Observe the effects when used as a value type:

```
var a = new Foo() { Value = 3 };
var b = a; // copies value
b.Value = 4;
Console.WriteLine( "a has {0}", a.Value ); //output: a has 3
Console.WriteLine( "b has {0}", b.Value ); //output: b has 4
```

Now look what happens when you cast it to the interface:

```
var a = new Foo() { Value = 3 } as IFoo; //boxed
var b = a; // copies reference
b.Value = 4;
Console.WriteLine( "a has {0}", a.Value ); //output: a has 4
Console.WriteLine( "b has {0}", b.Value ); //output: b has 4
```

So it doesn't matter whether a struct or class implements the interface. If cast to the interface and then is passed around under the interface, then it will behave as a reference type.

**Edit**: So if these are your requirements...

> For contract X:
>
> 1. Throw a compile error if a struct implements/inherits X.
> 2. X may not be an abstract class.

Well, you're simply stuck then, because those contradict each other.

- The only way to get a compile error if the struct implements/inherits the contract is if it is an abstract class.
- Since you can't use an abstract class in order to keep inheritance options open, you have to use an interface.
- The only ways to enforce the rule that a struct cannot implement the interface will be during run-time.

Using the constraint `where T: class, IFoo` wouldn't even work all the time. If I had this method (based on the same `Foo` and `IFoo` above):

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T foo) where T: class, IFoo {
    foo.Value += 1;
    Console.WriteLine( "foo has {0}", foo.Value );
}
```

Then it would throw a compile error under this circumstance:

```
var a = new Foo(){ Value = 3 };
DoSomething(a);
```

But it would work just fine under this circumstance:

```
var a = new Foo(){ Value = 3} as IFoo; //boxed
DoSomething(a);
```

So as far as I'm concerned, use `where T: class, IFoo`-style constraint, and then it may not matter if a struct implements the interface as long as it is boxed. Depends on what checking EF does if passed a boxed struct, though. Maybe it will work.

If it doesn't work, at least the generic constraint gets you part-way there, and you can check `foo.GetType().IsValueType` (referring to my `DoSomething` method above) and throw an `ArgumentException` to handle the case of boxed structs.

Comment: I know it does make a difference, and what I want to do here is to force the implementing type to be a reference type, i.e. make your first code example fail compilation (giving me an error that `Foo` must be a reference type, or something). In other words, my concern is not "what happens if a struct implements my interface?", but rather "how do I make sure a struct never does?".

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx. Looks like you can specify it's a "class", which means reference type.

Comment: True, but thats not what OP is asking for (he's already using type constrains infact)

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can restrict interfaces in that way unfortunatly. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) interfaces can be implemented by any type, both structs and classes :/

Comment: General interfaces, yes - but is there a way to apply a type constraint on the interface itself?

Comment: im not sure i understand the distinction, but to my knowledge its not possible to put that kind of resrictions on an interface. Can you elaborate on the problems you're seeing with type constraints though? That would seem like the best solution to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The boxing behavior of mutable structs cast as interfaces can certainly be annoying.  I don't know that a prohibition on all structs would be necessary, though.  There are a number of cases where it may be useful to have an immutable struct wrapping a class object (e.g. one way of implementing something like a Dictionary which supports multiple ways of enumeration would have been to have Dictionary.Keys and Dictionary.Values both be structures, each holding a reference to a Dictionary, and each providing a special GetEnumerator method; Dictionary isn't implemented that way, but it's not a bad pattern).  Such a pattern may avoid boxing in cases where one calls GetEnumerator on the object directly (as vb.net and c# both do with their duck-typed foreach loops); because the structures are immutable, even when boxing does occur it's a performance issue rather than a correctness one.