# Multiple constraints on type parameters with interface and class

Tags: c#

I have       `void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, ISpecificEntity;`
I just want use class of specific interface.

what the point of that?
I can use       `void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : ISpecificEntity;`

But I do not want to implement structure. I just want use class of some interface.

Yes. I can remove class. But how not to implement structure?

Comment: where T : class

Comment: I think that I can remove class. yes. But i do not want implement structure.

Comment: for example. theoretically I can inherit struct from interface. And i do not wanna use this struct in Add func.

Comment: The method says what it needs. You need to implement the interface. Why do you _not_ want to implement it? Or are you saying you want only a class to be accepted (not a struct)? If so, you can't do that at compile time.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I just see not my code and think why it uses  : class, ISpecificEntity instead of ISpecificEntity

Comment: I want implement interface. but only class need to be accepted.

Comment: You can't do that. Generics don't allow that. You can check the type at runtime if you really want to, but not compile time.

Comment: please give me link, What do you mean by "generics can`t do that"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify that an interface can only be implemented by reference types C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244680/specify-that-an-interface-can-only-be-implemented-by-reference-types-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `class,` *in practice* achieves in your example is it makes it *harder* (but not impossible) to pass in value types.

An example is below. With the `class` constraint, the `(ISpecificEntity)` needs to be there. Without the `class` constraint the `(ISpecificEntity)` does not need to be there.

It is a common misconception that `class` does not allow `struct`s to be passed in. This is not true. It basically means "this type must be a class *or an interface*".

If you really must disallow value types, you will need to check the value of `entity.GetType().IsValueType` *inside* the method (i.e. at runtime).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Bob
    {
        public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, ISpecificEntity
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entity.GetType().IsValueType);
            Console.WriteLine("added");
        }
    }

    public interface ISpecificEntity
    {

    }

    public struct SpecificEntity : ISpecificEntity
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var entity = new SpecificEntity();

            var bob = new Bob();

            bob.Add((ISpecificEntity)entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct! when i change it to 2 params with 'class' keyword it can`t  work but like in another example I can simply pass it with bob.Add(entity as ISpecificEntity); And it would work anyway! Thanks!